# Why do some people remember past lives who were not saints? Is there any Scriptural basis for this?

Tags: reference-request, evidence, reference

See, there are many who remember past lives like they were brutally killed by something or had intense consciousness at time of death. My question is that they were not real saints in previous life so, how can they have such memories.

[Don't downvote Or flag my question.This is not a scientific speculation but a request for reference]

References
[Shanti devi/Lugdi Devi](https://psi-encyclopedia.spr.ac.uk/articles/shanti-devi-reincarnation-case)

[A book as example](https://med.virginia.edu/perceptual-studies/publications/books-by-dops-faculty/study-of-reincarnation/children-who-remember-previous-lives-a-question-of-reincarnation/)
Many books by Ian Stevenson and Jim Tucker have been written on topic .

Main question

***Are there any verses in scripture which say if one face very intense emotions and thoughts during death and he /she isn't a saint /guru/ yogi? So he/she will remember past lives.***

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151744/discussion-on-question-by-hope-why-do-some-people-remember-past-lives-who-were-n); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Suppose a person practices Yogis sadhanas for several lives and obtains the siddhi but at the same time commits a heinous crime which gets him born in a not so blessed family in the next.But he might still retain the siddhi which had earned. Karma is extremely complicated and there might exist such explanations for the cases you've mentioned. @Hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manu Smriti 4.148. By daily reciting the Veda, by (the observance of
> the rules of) purification, by (practising) austerities, and by doing
> no injury to created beings, one (obtains the faculty of) remembering
> former births.

So, it's possible that some people have performed the necessary austerities in their past births and are carrying the merits they have earned in those births on to the current one and by virtue of which they have the faculty of remembering their past lives. Although they might not be performing any austerities or Yogic practices in their current births.

Another question might be why the person who have done good don't be born in a vedic family or family of yogis/saints.

This might be an explanation

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 8, Verse 6

Whatever one remembers upon giving up the body at the time of death, O son of Kunti, one attains that state, being always absorbed in such contemplation.

Comment: Vedābhyāsa, etc. needs to be performed in the current life, to remember the past lives. This is made clear by Medhātithi himself. Also, if you check 4.149 that would make it even more clearer. So, your interpretation of the śloka is incorrect, as per the context. You made an out of context interpretation, in order to argue in support of the unverifiable claims of random people (particularly mlecchas) having remembrance. Firstly, if a person really has done such karman throughout prev. life, s/he wouldn't be born as a mleccha.

Comment: I have not seen or commented upon about who has made such claims .. my answer is about if one person received such faculty how could that be explained. Karmas and when they bear fruits are extremely difficult things to determine. Previous births sadhanas are certainly stored and carried forward and they may very well fructify in the current life @Bingming and that is my explanation which others might find it wrong.

Comment: *my answer is about if one person received such faculty how could that be explained*, yes, but both the ślokas 4.148-149 as per the traditional commentators (4.149 talking about the present life itself), are talking about efforts in the current life to attain remembrance, and not efforts in prev. life fructifying as remembrance (of past lives) in the next life. Just like you gave an explanation, I also pointed a fault in your interpretation. Of course, since it's your answer, you are free to give an explanation, which you find correct.

Comment: The verse does not explicitly state that the fruits of the austerities will have to received in the same birth only .. usually no one knows when fruits of austerities will bear fruits (mostly fruits of Sadhanas are received in next births). And my answer is based on the verse itself and not on any commentary but if you say that based on a commentary my answer is faulty then I am ok with it @Bingming

Comment: @Rickross can u share an authentic url for manusmritu ?

Comment: @SpiritualAspirant you can read from here -- https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi